# Page Caching for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

How to do page caching in rails 3. Is there is any plugins or gem for that? whether page_cache_fu will work for rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it directly in the controller. Below is directly from the Rails Guide

```
class ProductsController < ActionController
  caches_page :index
  def index
    @products = Products.all
  end
end
```