# Page Caching in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there is any good page caching plugins available for rails 3. I had used page_cache_fu till now. When I shifted to rails 3 its showing to_prepare method error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page Caching for rails 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861635/page-caching-for-rails-3)

Comment: You already ask the same question :'(

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a separate plugin?
What's wrong with built-in page caching, fragment caching and action caching?